# How do i make eslint to work when building a react application in circleci?

Tags: continuous-integration, create-react-app, eslint, circleci

I config eslint on my personal project to allow `console.log` to be a warning instead of an error so on local my app is compiled successfully.

When i run `npm run build` in local

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

src/components/ReduxName/ReduxName.tsx
  Line 12:3:  Unexpected console statement  no-console

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

This is fine everything's working like it should.
But when i run in circleci

```
Creating an optimized production build...

Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
Most CI servers set it automatically.

Failed to compile.

src/components/ReduxName/ReduxName.tsx
  Line 12:3:  Unexpected console statement  no-console
```

Seems like circleci doesn't recognize my eslint setting ???
Any idea how to get through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turned out the problem was right in front of my eyes

```
Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
Most CI servers set it automatically.
```

Warnings are treated as errors on CI on of course my app can't be compiled.
I fixed it by specifically make `console.log` not a warning in eslint and problem solved.